# Show value of a sub-field in table mode

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, robo3t

I use Robo 3T to query data in remote server.

I like its `table mode` to display data

Now, I want to display `ipInfo.region` alongside each document to see this information easily.

Does anyone know how to write a query to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation pipeline and **$addFields** operator to add new field while listing the data, below query will add an extra field in your table to show nested data ipInfo.region

```
db.getCollection('logs').aggregate( [
   {
     $addFields: {
       ipInfoRegion: "$ipInfo.region" 
     }
   }
] )
```